# FEDORA IPTABLES Block specific IP Address

Tags: linux, iptables, unix, fedora, firewalld

The below is the rule that i had added to my iptables.. Still the result of the below rules for me is ssh is blocked from everywhere..

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  1.2.3.4              anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             1.2.3.4               tcp dpt:ssh
```

Comment: this command makes sense if the global policy is to drop packets, and you open that ip address for ssh trafic only.

Comment: Sorry for the typo error, @natxoasenjo , I corrected the que... I put the same but not working out for a specific IP, If i type  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  --dport 22 -j DENY to deny everything it is working,Dont know where iam making mistake

Answer (score 2):

That command is to explicitly allow (ACCEPT) connection from a given IP address

Change the `-j ACCEPT` to `-j DROP` to deny access.

This will also depend on what your default action is.

Comment: Sorry for the typo error, @hardillb , I corrected the que... I put the same but not working out for a specific IP, If i type  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  --dport 22 -j DENY to deny everything it is working

Comment: Dont know where iam making mistake